# How do I reload Django model-forms?

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

Currently my models look similar to this,

```
def feature_tuples():
    features = (('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b'))
    return features

class Sample(models.Model):
choices_tuple = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True, choices=feature_tuples())
```

I than created a model form of this model. However, at some point the user can change the options from (a, b) to (c, d) or any other charecters.
The choices of `choices_tuple` shoud also be changed from a, b to c, d. I can't find a way to reload them in the form. Help?

Comment: You don't. In that case it is better to work with an extra model and a `ForeignKey`, but what is more problematic is that your question does not specify when to use `a` and `b`; and when to use `c` and `d`.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem The user can change them. I will accept his choices in a view, but I can't add those choices in the actual model.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want dynamically set choices for a model field then you can create a modelform for that model and set dynamic choices in ****init**** method of modelform.

Note: Do not set **choices** attribute in model. If you set **choices** in model field then it only accept those choice_value.

```
from django import forms


class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    
    default_choices = [('a', 'a'), ('b', 'b')]

    choices_tuple = forms.ChoiceField(choices=default_choices, required=False)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(YourModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['choices_tuple'].choices = self.get_dynamic_choice()
            

    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = ['choices_tuple']

    def get_dynamic_choice(self):
        ''' you can set choices'''
        choices = [('c', 'c'), ('d', 'd')]
        return choices
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man. Seems to somewhat get the job done.